# ¿Cómo invocar un Activity A con datos, un Activity B y regresar de B con datos sin perder los datos de A?

Tags: android, google-maps

Necesito hacer un registro de coordenadas con Google Maps, ya obtengo las coordenadas desde google maps, pero el problema está en que tengo un Activity A con un formulario en el cual lleno datos y un boton que abre un Activity B con Google Maps para obtener las coordenadas, pero si yo ya llené algunos campos del formulario del Activity A, quisiera regresar con las coordenadas obtenidas en B sin perder los campos ya rellenados.
¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Has probado con los [intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters?hl=es-419) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde la Actividad A debes lanzar la B con un startActivityForResult (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result?hl=es-419):

```
REQUEST_CODE=1312 // el numero que quieras

Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Desde la B, una vez tengas el resultado la finalizas con un setResult:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra(COORDENADAS_KEY, coordenadas);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); // si cancela puedes poner un setResult(RESULT_CANCELED)
finish();
```

Y de nuevo en la actividad A sobrescribes onActivityResult para capturar ese resultado y mostrarlo en tu vista:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            coordenadas = intent.getExtra(COORDENADAS_KEY);
            // TODO realizar el tratamiento necesario para esas coordenadas
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar de lanzarle lo siguiente:,

Activity A utilizas un intent (**.putExtra()**):

```java
Intent i=new Intent(this,Actividad2.class); //ejemplo: Intent i=new Intent(tuActivityActual.this,ActivityDestino.class);
i.putExtra("coordenada1", et1.getText().toString()); //ejemplo: i.putExtra("coordenada1", variableCondatos);
i.putExtra("coordenada2", et2.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

Activity B recogemos los datos con un bundle (**getIntent**().**getExtras**()):

```java
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String lng=bundle.getString("coordenada1");
String lat=bundle.getString("coordenada2");
```

Esos string se lo asignas donde desees ya tendrías tus coordenadas de Activity A en B.

y si necesitas un activity C pues vuelves a hacer lo mismo depende del ciclo de vida que quieras darle a estos datos.

Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [answer] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus respuestas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.